# nginx `/var/www/foo/current/public` forbidden error 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano3

Nginx default configuration file - `/etc/nginx/sites-available/foo`

```
upstream puma {
     server unix:///var/www/foo/shared/tmp/sockets/foo-puma.sock;
   }

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name foo.com;

      if ($http_user_agent ~* (easou|Gimme60bot) ) {
          return 403;
      }
      root /var/www/foo/current/public;

      client_max_body_size 15M;
      keepalive_timeout 10;


      location ~ ^/(images|stylesheets|javascripts|fonts) {
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      }

      location ^~ /assets/ {
       gzip_static on;
       expires max;
       add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

    location ~* ^.*system.*\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

}
```

---

```
[error] 10400#10400: *2 directory index of "/var/www/foo/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 10.16.10.20, server: foo.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.foo.com", referrer: "http://www.foo.com/"
```

I also try to change `current/public` directory permission but it's not worked.
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/foo/current/public`
                  OR
`sudo chown -R deploy:deploy /var/www/foo/current/public`

Comment: Have you tried using `chmod` on the said directory?

Comment: yes, i changed the permissions of directories but didn't worked. When i moved application from /var/www/foo/current/public to /home/user/apps/appname/ then it is working.